# CSS link button not responsive

Tags: css, html, ui

I am creating a link button purely using CSS and HTML. This is because I want to pass the html structure to an external system. It works perfectly fine when the browser tab is maximized. but when I reduce the browser page screen size, the button becomes and smaller and does not show it correctly. below is my snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Link Button</h2>

<p>A link styled as a button:</p>
<a href="default.asp" target="_blank">
<p style="text-decoration: none;color: white;font-size:24px; text-align:center;margin-right:1100px;margin-left:25px;margin-top:0px;margin:bottom:0px;padding-left:1em;padding:right:1em;border:1px solid black;background:green;">This is a link</p></a>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: This look correctly in full size screen]

[image: When I reduce the size of the window it is not responsive to the size.]

How can I reduce the button size as we reduce the window's size.
Note : I can only use style tag as the external system expects that for styling. I cannot use the slds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `margin-right`.
If you need the button to not exceed a certain size you should set a `max-width` so that the button can't grow past that size (e.g.:`max-width: 250px;`) but can still get smaller when the window gets resized.